Ubuntu 22.04 lts intune
I'm trying to install intune portal on a new Ubuntu 24.04 VM guest OS using sudo apt install intune-portal and this output is displayed:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:  
intune-portal: 
  Depends: libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37 (>= 2.39.90) but 2.36.0-2ubuntu1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.


Assuming you followed the instructions from the official page, you should have added the new repository.
If so, check out this answer here which covers resolving unmet dependencies after adding a new repository.
